# Cannot create Ingress for Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, prometheus, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to create an entry for Prometheus.

I have `nodePort` service deployed like this :

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: prometheus
 namespace: monitoring
labels:
 app: prometheus
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
  - port: 9090
    targetPort: 9090
    nodePort: 31190
    protocol: TCP
selector:
 app: prometheus
```

And my Ingress is :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: prometheus-ingress
 namespace: monitoring
 annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
 rules:
- host: prometheus.example.com
  http:
    paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: prometheus
          servicePort: 9090
```

Can you explain me why my ingress didn't work ?

Comment: How are you testing if it works or not? You curl it?

Comment: Yes I trying and it didn't work.

Comment: can you paste the test? what's your curl command?

Comment: You are not using an ingress controller properly here, use an annotation in your ingress like `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` depending on the kind of controller you are using.

Comment: Paste the error (and other steps you've executed to debug it) please **to the question**.

Comment: Also provide `kubectl describe ingress` output of your ingress object.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus
            port:
              number: 9090
```